# CakePHP-mongodb one record not displayed

Tags: mongodb, cakephp

I'm new to cakePHP with mongoDB and stuck somewhere. My data is in a collection users. When I fetch data, if there are 3 records only 2 are displayed and if there is one record nothing is displayed. When I use print_r to print the array it shows one of the array blank every time. The records are fetched but one record is not displayed at any time. Cannot figure out why is this happening.

UsersController.php

```
public function index() {
              $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
              $data = $this->Paginator->paginate('User');
              $this->set('users', $data);
      }
```

This is how I fetch the records

index.ctp

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
<td><?php echo h($user['User']['firstname']);?></td>
```

Only the last record is not displayed. Here are the images that should clear the problem
[lastname ascending](http://s24.postimg.org/cmyev9cxx/records_1.png) and [lastname descending](http://s24.postimg.org/r4vm39491/records_2.png). See the records are present but don't know why not displayed.

Comment: can you add more code for view `index.ctp`, you can also debug your variables in view file using debug or pr to see exact issue

Comment: @Abhishek Already used debug here's what it gives. [link]http://s14.postimg.org/yjra9vga9/debugged.png